# When will I receive a inbox message for a comment?

Tags: support, comments

I used to think that, when I'm not the author of a post, I'll only receive a inbox message as a reminder for a comment if I've commented under the post and another commenter under the post adds a @xzczd in his comment, but recently I found there seems to be some exceptions, for example, I received a reminder for [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97993/solve-tricky-nonlinear-ode-on-a-grid?noredirect=1#comment265882_97993), no "@" therein.

So in what cases will I receive the reminder for a comment? This seems not to be explained in the helper center, I believe it has been explained somewhere else but failed to find it.

Comment: Is anything here ([How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)) of any help?

Comment: @MarcoB This is a good summary for the usage of @, but it seems not to address the issue I mentioned above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second bullet point in the [first answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020) to the [post I linked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019) in my comment mentions the following (emphasis mine):

> "Note if a user comments *on their own post* and there is *only one person* who has previously commented, then that person is also notified if @name is not included."

I think that describes what happened to you:

- You were the first to comment on Jane Doe's post
- then Jane Doe commented on her own post right after you,
- which triggered that rule and you got notified even without @.

The system assumes that the post author is responding to your comment since it's the only other earlier comment there, even though a ping handle has not been included.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that line!… Thx for pointing out.